# How can I call a function on a button being enabled in Angular 8?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular8

Below is a snippet of my sign-in.component.html file. I have a function within the corresponding sign-in.component.ts file which I would like to call on the button below becoming enabled. An example of what I hope to achieve:

```
<div class="button-container">
    <button mat-raised-button [disabled]="!signInForm.valid" (enabled)="callAFunction()" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ngOnInit` function, subscribe on `signInForm.valueChanges` to call `callAFunction()`.

```js
ngOnInit(){
  this.signInForm.valueChanges.subscribe(v => {
    if (this.signInForm.valid) {
      callAFunction();
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition for the button to be enabled is by:

```
signInForm.valid
```

So I guess you could add a

```
<input type="text" (ngModelChange)="theFunctionYouWantToCallWhenSignInFormIsValid()"/>
```

With this, as soon as your form is valid, the function that you want to call will get triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if the `callAFunction()` is not returning anything this is the method you can use:

```
<div class="button-container">
    <button mat-raised-button [disabled]="!signInForm.valid" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    {{ signInForm.valid ? callAFunction() : '' }}
</div>
```

if `callAFunction()` is returning something then you need to subscribe for change in the signInForm.valid like:

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.signInSub = this.signInForm.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
     this.signedIn.vaild ? callAFunction() : '';  
   });
}
ngOnDestroy(){
   this.signInSub.unsubscribe();
}
```